# minitest shows error while testing carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, minitest

I am trying to test picture uploads using carrierwave. I am following this tutorial.
https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/carrierwave-rails-test-fixtures/ but getting errors.

models/product_test.rb
require './test/test_helper'

```
class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

   test "has an avatar" do
      product = products(:one)
      assert File.exists?(product.pictures.file.path)
   end
  test "uploads an avatar" do
     product = Product.create!(:pictures, 
     fixture_file_upload('/files/cat_1.jpg', 'image/jpg'))
     assert(File.exists?(product.reload.pictures.file.path))
  end
 end
```

fixtures/product.yml

```
   id: 1
   title: shirt
   exhibited_at: <%= Time.now %>
   description: MyString
   pictures: 'cat_1.jpg'
```

model/product.rb

```
mount_uploaders :pictures, PictureUploader
```

error message

```
  E

  Error:
  ProductTest#test_has_an_avatar:
  ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave- 
  1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:448:in `initialize'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave- 
  1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:448:in `new'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave- 
  1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:448:in `_mounter'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave- 
  1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:296:in `pictures'
  /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/carrierwave- 
  1.2.3/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:366:in `pictures'

  bin/rails test test/models/product_test.rb:19

  E

 Error:
 ProductTest#test_uploads_an_avatar:
 NoMethodError: undefined method `fixture_file_upload' for # 
 <ProductTest:0x00000006ae2468>
 Did you mean?  fixture_path


 bin/rails test test/models/product_test.rb:25
```

Comment: unclosed parenthesis here: `product = Product.create!(:pictures, `

Comment: the parenthesis is closed on the next line

Comment: oh never mind, i didn't see the `fixture_file_upload())`

Comment: I think you need to `include ActionDispatch::TestProcess` in `ProductTest` class, and change `Product.create!(:pictures, 
     fixture_file_upload('/files/cat_1.jpg', 'image/jpg'))` to `Product.create!(pictures: fixture_file_upload('/files/cat_1.jpg', 'image/jpg'))`

Comment: thank you so much. I did the way you said. but both the test cases now showing argument error                                                                                  
          ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0)